# Angular 2 keyboard event triggering safety button

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-events

I have an issue with the code below with IE11 triggering the safety button as pictured below[image]

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
})
class AppComponent { 
  @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
  doSomething($event) {
    // alt + s
    if($event.altKey && $event.altKey === 83) {
        // perform some action
        // saveForm();

        // also added this but still triggering in IE11
        $event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried adding $event.preventDefault(), $event.stopPropagation(), $event.cancelBubble = true; and few others.

My problem is it is executing the `saveForm();` but also triggering the safety button in IE11. How can i stop the Safety button from opening up in IE?

Comment: try returning false after $event.preventDefault();

Comment: @mvermand Tried that. same result. no effect.

Comment: Is your doSomething method called? (breakpoint, console.log...)

Comment: @mvermand Yes it is being called. I can debug in chrome too.

Comment: can you make a Plunker or so to demonstrate? Please also add the exact version of IE. I to have IE11 but it looks different than on your image.

Comment: Maybe all i want is https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_accesskey.asp. I don't have access to my work PC so can't test out. Looks like I am an idiot all along. Will report if this works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using accesskey is the solution.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_accesskey.asp